# xpath queries for subsetting pairs of nodes

Tags: xml, r, xpath

Question on the best way to go about subsetting from an XML document in R

Imagine I have an XML document which some structure like this in the middle somewhere:

```
<A>
  <B> 1 </B>
  <C> 2 </C>
  <D> 3 </D>
  <E> lots of other stuff, child nodes, etc </E>
</A>
<A>
  <B> 5 </B>
  <C> 6 </C>
  <D> 7 </D>
  <E> lots of other stuff </E>
</A>
<A>
  <B> 1 </B>
  <D> 2 </D>
  <E> lots of other stuff </E>
</A>
```

I'd like to create a table that has a row for each node `A` with columns of the `B` and `C` values.

I cannot just do

```
Bs <- xpathSApply(doc, "//x:B", xmlValue, namespaces="x")
Cs <- xpathSApply(doc, "//x:C", xmlValue, namespaces="x")
data.frame(Bs, Cs)
```

Because some of the nodes are missing the "C" element, so these vectors will be different lengths and not align in general.

Instead, I can do something like:

```
N <- getNodeSet(doc, "//x:A", namespaces="x")
Bs <- sapply(N, function(x) xmlValue(x[["B"]])
Cs <- sapply(N, function(x) xmlValue(x[["C"]])
```

Which is okay when both nodes are the same depth, but does not generalize if node C is some long xpath expression deep inside node A.  One would think that I could just `sapply` over the xpath call instead,

```
Cs <- sapply(N, xpathSApply, "<some_xpath_xpr>", xmlValue))
```

but Lo and Behold! this does not do at all what we think -- the xpathSApply accesses the whole `xmlInternalDocument` each time, not just the xml node it was given.  Trying to follow the trick shown in the documentation for subsetting,

```
N1 = xmlDoc(N[[1]])
xpathSApply(N1, ...)
free(N1)
```

inside the `sapply` is just asking for a segfault....

Any hints? Maybe I am going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely that your `"<some_xpath_expr>"` looks like `"//C"`.
It needs to be `".//C"`.  The . at the beginning says start from where you 
currently are, i.e. each node in N.

BTW, there should be no need for free() anymore. I'll update the documentation.
Thanks for pointingthat out.